# При обновлении Ubuntu 18.04 возникает ошибка

Tags: ubuntu

Помогите, пожалуйста. При обновлении(*sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade*) Ubuntu 18.04 возникает следующая ошибка:

```
Пропускается получение настроенного файла «main/binary-i564/Packages», так как репозиторий «http://deb.playonlinux.com precise InRelease» не поддерживает архитектуру «i564»

Пропускается получение настроенного файла «stable/source/Sources», так как репозиторий «https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease» его не предоставляет (возможно, репозиторий указан с ошибкой в sources.list?)
E: Репозиторий «http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu bionic Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройке пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).
N: Пропускается получение настроенного файла «main/binary-i564/Packages», так как репозиторий «http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease» не поддерживает архитектуру «i564»
```

и таких еще несколько.Вроде нормально работает, но мне не нравится это. Так как я правильно понимаю, что не обновился система?
В чем может быть ошибка? Я недавно перешел на Ubuntu и многого еще не знаю, пожалуйста, помогите. Буду очень благодарен, за любой ответ..

Comment: Видимо вы добавили в систему левый репозиторий выполнив что-нить вроде `sudo add-apt-repository`

Comment: *sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin  |||||||||||||||||||||||
     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js  ||||||||||||||||||||||||||
     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js  ||||||||||||||||||||||||||
     sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386   |||||||||||||||||||||||||
     sudo dpkg --add-architecture i564   |||||||||||||||||||||||||
     wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O - | sudo apt-key add -* 
  ||||||||||||||||||||||||||

|||||||||||||||||||||| - ОЗНАЧАЕТ РАЗДЕЛЕНИЕ

Comment: ЭТО ВРОДЕ ВСЕ ЧТО ДОБАВИЛ ПОСЛЕДНИЙ РАЗ, НАШЕЛ В ИСТОРИИ ТЕРМИНАЛА..
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| МНОГО ТАКИХ ОЗНАЧАЕТ РАЗДЕЛЕНИЕ МЕЖДУ КОМАНДАМИ, А ТО ТУТ ПРИ НАЖАТИИ ENTER ВСЕ РАВНО СЛИТНО ПИШЕТ ВСЕ, ПО ЭТОМУ..

Comment: дааа, оказывается я добавил эту архитектуру i564, наверное нужен был. И что мне делать??  Архитектура i564 не обновляется..

Comment: Главное - держать исправный бекап. У них в основном репозитории бардак, а в сторонних и подавно.

Comment: В Ubuntu 18.04 PlayOnLinux ставится из **стандартного** репозитория. Так что каменть лишний мусор и будет тебе счастье.